# What tag should we use for answer-dependent challenges?

Tags: discussion, tags

By my count, we've had at least 5 "answer-dependent" challenges now, starting with [Evolution of "Hello, World!"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/40376/8478). I think it's time we started tagging these, so we can put some general information in the tag wiki, and it's immediately apparent that a challenge is of this type.

So, here's another Good Ol' Meta Poll™.

When voting, keep in mind, that in general, answers won't necessarily just depend on the answer, but potentially on some or all or the existing answers (we didn't really have that yet, but we might not want to preclude the tag from including those).

Please cast your vote under the premise that answer-dependent challenges *are* on-topic for PPCG. If you disagree, the place to discuss that is [this question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2415/8478).

Comment: When I think about it "answer-dependent challenge" is kind of misleading. All challenges "depend" on answers. The point to get across is that the answers depend on each other.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies "interdependent-answers"? ;) sounds more like a KotH to me though

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We should create the tag [answer-chaining](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-chaining).

Comment: I think this is one of the clearest and simplest so far.

Comment: answer-chaining - what do you mean by chain here ? chain does not really tell that the answer is dependent on any previous one.. or its answer number

Comment: @Optimizer "chain does not really tell that the answer is dependent on any previous one"? What do you think a chain is?

Comment: @feersum I'm guessing that what Optimizer meant is that each link in a "chain" is dependent on the link *directly* before it. It doesn't cover challenges where answers can depend on *any* of the answers before it.

Comment: Chainmail depends on multiple links :P

Comment: I like this tag, but I don't think it fits ALL of the answer dependent questions. For example, what if there was a challenge where you have to use a language that hasn't been used yet? Each new answer isn't necessarily "chained" to the one immediately before it, but it is dependent on all previous answers.

Answer (score 4):

We should create the tag [progressive-answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/progressive-answers).

Answer (score 2):

We should create the tag [ordered-answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ordered-answers).

Comment: +1 (can't vote). While not particularly interesting, it seems very clear to me.

Comment: ordered-answers - looks like the answer itself has to be ordered of some kind.

Answer (score 1):

We should create the tag [answer-dependent](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-dependent).

Comment: -1 (can't vote). This name makes sense if you know what you're talking about, but if you don't, I think it's not very clear. (See CH's comment on the question.)

Answer (score 0):

We should create the tag [answer-progression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-progression) (or [answer-progressions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-progressions)).

Comment: +1 from me (can't vote)

Comment: +1 for the singular. (I *have* voted, just wanted to clarify that I'm not a fan of the plural.)

Answer (score 0):

We should add the tag [chronological-answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chronological-answers).

Answer (score -1):

We should create the tag [domino-coding](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domino-coding).

Comment: This seems to fit, but there have also been domino themed questions so it clashes

Answer (score -3):

We should create the tag [incremental-answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/incremental-answers).

Comment: -1 (can't vote). The relationship between answers can't necessarily be described as "incremental".

Comment: I think incremental answers could be an entirely different challenge type, so it doesn't work here

Answer (score -3):

We should create tag [evolving-answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evolving-answers)

This signifies that the subsequent answers evolve based on the previous ones.

Comment: +1 (can't vote)

Answer (score -3):

We should create tag [answer-evolution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-evolution)

This signifies that the subsequent answers evolve based on the previous ones.

(Same meaning as previous one, just that a different term)

Comment: +1 (can't vote)

Answer (score -5):

We should create the tag [answer-answering](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answer-answering).

Answer (score -7):

There is no need for such a tag.

Comment: -1 (can't vote)

Answer (score -7):

We should create the tag [conga-line](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conga-line)  :)

Comment: Funny, but confusing :P

Answer (score -9):

We should create the tag [chinese-whispers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chinese-whispers).